# Trying to understand default constructors and member initialisatioon

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I am used to initialising member variables in class constructors, but I thought I'd check out if default values are set by default constructors. My tests were with Visual Studio 2022 using the C++ 20 language standard. The results confused me:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    double r;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() = default;
    double r;
};

class C
{
public:
    C() {}
    double r;
};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    std::cout << a1.r << std::endl; // ERROR: uninitialized local variable 'a1' used

    A a2();
    std::cout << a2.r << std::endl; // ERROR: left of '.r' must have class/struct/union

    A* pa1 = new A;
    std::cout << pa1->r << std::endl; // output: -6.27744e+66

    A* pa2 = new A();
    std::cout << pa2->r << std::endl; // output: 0

    B b1;
    std::cout << b1.r << std::endl; // ERROR: uninitialized local variable 'b1' used

    B b2();
    std::cout << b2.r << std::endl; // ERROR: left of '.r' must have class/struct/union

    B* pb1 = new B;
    std::cout << pb1->r << std::endl; // output: -6.27744e+66

    B* pb2 = new B();
    std::cout << pb2->r << std::endl; // output: 0

    C c1;
    std::cout << c1.r << std::endl;  // output: -9.25596e+61

    C c2();
    std::cout << c2.r << std::endl; // ERROR: left of '.r' must have class/struct/union

    C* pc1 = new C;
    std::cout << pc1->r << std::endl; // output: -6.27744e+66

    C* pc2 = new C();
    std::cout << pc2->r << std::endl; // output: -6.27744e+66
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can enlighten me.

Comment: Which part is confusing? There are 2 different things - about unitilised values and `left of '.r' must have class/struct/union`, which is most vexing parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see what is happening on case by case basis in your given example.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statements:

```
A a1; //this creates a variable named a1 of type A using the default constrcutor
std::cout << a1.r << std::endl; //this uses the uninitialized data member r which leads to undefined behavior
```

In the above snippet, the first statement creates a variable named `a1` of type `A` using the **default ctor** `A::A()` **synthesized** by the compiler. This means that the data member `r` will **default initialized**. And since `r` is of built-in type, it will have **undeterminate value**. Using this **uninitilized** variable which you do when you wrote the second statement shown in the above snippet is **undefined behavior**.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statements:

```
A a2(); //this is a function declaration 
std::cout << a2.r << std::endl; //this is not valid since a2 is the name of a function
```

The first statement in the above snippet, **declares** a function named `a2` that takes no parameters and has the return type of `A`. That is, the first statement is actually a **function declaration**. Now, in the second statement you're trying to access a data member `r` of the function named `a2` which doesn't make any sense and hence you get the mentioned error.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statements:

```
A* pa1 = new A; 
std::cout << pa1->r << std::endl; // output: -6.27744e+66
```

The first statement in the above snippet has the following effects:

1. an unnamed object of type `A` is created on the heap due to `new A` using the **default constructor** `A::A()` **synthesized** by the compiler. Moreover, we also get a pointer to this unnamed object as a result.
2. Next, the pointer that we got in step 1 above, is used as an **initializer** for `pa1`. That is, a pointer to `A` named `pa1` is created and is initialized by the pointer to the unnamed object that we got in step 1 above.

Since, the default constructor was used(see step 1) this means that the data member `r` of the unnamed object is **default initilaized**. And since the data member `r` is of built in type, this implies that it has **indeterminate value**. And using this uninitialized data member `r` which you do in the second statement of the above code snippet, is **undefined behavior**. This is why you get some garbage value as output.

##### Case 4

Here we consider the statements:

```
A* pa2 = new A();
std::cout << pa2->r << std::endl;
```

The first statement of the above snippet has the following effects:

1. An unnamed object of type `A` is created due to the expression `new A()`. But this time since you have used parenthesis `()` and since class `A` does not have an user provided default constructor, this means **value initialization** will happen. This essentially means that the data member `r` will be **zero initialized**. This is why/how you get the output as `0` in the second statement of the above snippet. Moreover, a pointer to this unnamed object is returned as the result.
2. Next, a pointer to `A` named `pa2` is created and is initialized using the pointer to the unnamed object that we got in step 1 above.

---

Exactly the same thing happens with the next 4 statements related to class `B`. So i am not discussing the next 4 statements that are related to class `B` since we will learn nothing new from them. The same thing will happen for them as for the previous 4 statement described above.

---

Now will consider the statements related to class `C`. We're not skipping over these 4 statements because for class `C` there is a user-defined default constructor.

##### Statement 5

Here we consider the statements:

```
C c1;
std::cout << c1.r << std::endl;
```

The first statement of the above snippet creates a variable named `c1` of type `C` using the user provided **default constructor** `A::A()`. Since this user provided default constructor doesn't do anything, the data member `r` is left uninitialized and we get the same behavior as we discussed for `A a1;`. That is, using this uninitialized variable which you do in the second statement is **undefined behavior**.

##### Statement 6

Here we consider the statements:

```
C c2();
std::cout << c2.r << std::endl;
```

The first statement in the above snippet is a **function declaration**. Thus you'll get the same behavior/error that we got for class `A`.

##### Statement 7

Here we consider the statements:

```
C* pc1 = new C;
std::cout << pc1->r << std::endl;
```

The first statement in the above snippet has the following effects:

1. An unnamed object of type `C` is created on the heap using the user provided default constructor `A::A()` due to the expression `new A`. And since the user provide default constructor does nothing, the data member `r` is left uninitialized. Moreover, we get a pointer to this unnamed object as result.
2. Next, a pointer to `C` named `pc1` is created and is initialized by the pionter to unnamed object that we got in step 1.

Now the second statement in the above snippet, uses uninitialized data member `r` which is undefined behavior and explains why you are getting some garbage value as output.

##### Statement 8

Here we consider the statements:

```
C* pc2 = new C();
std::cout << pc2->r << std::endl;
```

The first statement of the above snippet has the following effects:

1. An unnamed object of type `C` is created on the heap due to `new C()`. Now since you have specificed parenthesis `()` this will do value-initialization. But because this time we've a user-provide default constructor, value-initialization is the same as default-initialization which will be done using the user-provide default constructor. And since the user provide default constructor does nothing, the data member `r` will be left uninitialized. Moreover, we get a pointer to the unnamed object as result.
2. Next, a pointer to `C` named `pc2` is created and is initialized by the pionter to unnamed object that we got in step 1 above.

Now the second statement in the above snippet, uses uninitialized data member `r` which is **undefined behavior** and explains why you are getting some garbage value as output.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in such detail.  This is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`A a2();`, `B b2();` and `C c2();` could also be parsed as declarations of functions returning `A`/`B`/`C` with empty parameter list. This interpretation is preferred and so you are declaring functions, not variables. This is also known as the "*most vexing parse*" issue.

None of the default constructors (including the implicit one of `A`) are initializing `r`, so it will have an indeterminate value. Reading that value will cause undefined behavior.

An exception are `A* pa2 = new A();` and `B* pb2 = new B();`. The `()` initializer does *value-initialization*. The effect of value-initialization is in these two cases that the whole object will be zero-initialized, because both `A` and `B` have a default constructor that is not user-provided. (Defaulted on first declaration doesn't count as user-provided.)

In case of `C` this doesn't apply, because `C`'s default constructor is user-provided and therefore value-initialization will only result in default-initialization, calling the default constructor, which doesn't initialize `r`.

Comment: Thanks.  The "most vexing parse" issue is appropriately named!

Answer (score 1):

```
MyType name(); // This is treated as a function declaration
MyType name{}; // This is the correct way
```